# R:Create loop or function for Moran I per region

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to this platform, so I hope I can make my problem clear as possible.

I have a dataset `all_regions` with the following column variables:
`all_regions$region`, `all_regions$participantID`, `all_regions$longitude.coordinates`, `all_regions$latitude.coordinates`, and `all_regions$score`.

I want to check the clustering per region for the variable score using the longitude and latitude coordinates. I have ~ 400.000 participants in 362 regions. I know what I have to do to calculate the Moran I value for one region:

#Extract data by region 1

```
region1 <- all_regions[all_regions$region == "region name"), ]
```

#generate a distance matrix for Moran I

```
dists1 <- as.matrix(dist(cbind(region1$longitude.coordinates, region1$latitude.coordinates))
```

#take the inverse of the matrix values for Moran I

```
dists.inv1 <- 1/dists1
```

#replace the diagonal entries with zero

```
diag(dists.inv1) <- 0
```

#replace Inf with NA

```
dists.inv1[sapply(dists.inv1, is.infinite)] <- NA
```

#calculate

```
result1 = Moran.I(dists.inv1$score,(is.na(dists.inv1)))

> result1 

$observed [1] 0.001937182

$expected [1] -0.001221001

$sd [1] 0.007965195

$p.value [1] 0.6917378
```

The results provide information about the following statistics: $observed, $expected, $sd, and $p.value.

**Doing this 362 times will take forever.**

I want to create a loop or function in which the above described happens for each region and saves in CSV, a data frame of whatever with region name and the $observed, $expected, $sd, and $p.value values so that I can see the results back in one file. Any idea how?